# How to create foreach if the data is same PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a array from database like this

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'B' => array(
        'company' => 'KC ACEH'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'company' => 'KCP ACEH DARUSSALAM'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'jumlah' => null,
        'jumbuy' => '50990',
        'admin' => '50010'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'B' => array(
        'company' => 'KC LANGSA'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'company' => 'KCP ACEH ULEE KARENG'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'jumlah' => null,
        'jumbuy' => '65000',
        'admin' => '5000'
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'B' => array(
        'company' => 'KC ACEH'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'company' => 'KCP ACEH DARUSSALAM'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'jumlah' => null,
        'jumbuy' => '98990',
        'admin' => '2010'
    )
)
```

)

array row zero and row one, is the same month and array row two is the different month. so I want to implement with foreach if the data of the name 'User' -> 'Company' is same . and this data will be output

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'B' => array(
        'company' => 'KC ACEH'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'company' => 'KCP ACEH DARUSSALAM'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'jumlah' => null,
        'jumbuy' => '50990',
        'admin' => '50010'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'jumlah' => null,
        'jumbuy' => '98990',
        'admin' => '2010'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'B' => array(
        'company' => 'KC LANGSA'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'company' => 'KCP ACEH ULEE KARENG'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'jumlah' => null,
        'jumbuy' => '65000',
        'admin' => '5000'
    )
)
```

)

i am search googling but i dont understand. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values from `['B']['company']` is going to be unique, then you could use that as your key into grouping those array batches that share those and put then inside another container.

On initial container push, just push the whole batch along with the assigned key. If its there already, just get the current batch's last element (the numeric index one) and push it into the group.

```
$data = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    if(!isset($data[$values['B']['company']])) {
        // initialize group
        $data[$values['B']['company']] = $values;
    } else {
        $last_element = array_pop($values); // get last element
        $data[$values['B']['company']][] = $last_element; // push
    }
}

$data = array_values($data); // re index
```

[Sample Output](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/Z84Hwa)

Comment: i'm sorry sir, i have a question again. so This data will be made into a graph , and the data is taken from the user data and jumbuy.

I 've managed to display User data , but I have not been able to display that jumbuy data. please help in order to perform jumbuy

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($report_posts as $values) {
        if(!isset($data[$values['User']['company']])) {
            $data[$values['User']['company']] = $values;

            $data1 = array(***OUTPUT JUMBUY***);
            $series = $this->HighCharts->addChartSeries();
            $series->addName($values['User']['company'])->addData($data1);
            $mychart->addSeries($series);

        } else {
            $last_element = array_pop($values);
            $data[$values['User']['company']][] = $last_element;

        }
    }
    $data = array_values($data);
```